# How to modify relevance in Marklogic 7.0?

Tags: marklogic

I am new in Marklogic. I have gone through the documents of Marklogic from there official website.

I am stucked at one place. As we know the marklogic gives the result in relevance form but if i want to modify this relevance format or may be add/remove some things as per need, who will I do this?

The tutorial provided on is giving the relevance detail but it is not giving how to modify it.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

[Chapter 8 of the Search Developer's Guide](https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/search-dev/relevance) talks a lot about relevance and how to adjust it. In general the scoring philosophy in MarkLogic Server is that we have a uniform hierarchical scoring model rather than a linear rank scoring model. So in general you'll be working better with the platform if you find ways to weight the factors you consider important so they naturally rise to the position in the ordering that you want.

If you have access to the recordings of the User Conference presentations, the Search talk summarizes a lot of the relevance-related features and the intuitions/tradeoffs of their use.

Comment: Thanks for reply       But i am not getting how will i adjust it.         Do anyone have any code or any setting for it.              Further help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot really influence the scoring formula itself. MarkLogic has a few standard calculation methods, but the default one is usually the best. You can however influence the relevance ranking in a few ways:

1. Apply different document qualities
2. Apply weights to sub-queries
3. Use boost-query

The first is very simple, but not very flexible. Simply specify a different document quality number at insert. Positive numbers will increase relevance score, negative numbers will descrease it. See also [https://docs.marklogic.com/xdmp:document-insert](https://docs.marklogic.com/xdmp%3adocument-insert).

The second isn't very complex either. And it is very flexible, as you can influence relevance ranking at run-time that way. It does require understanding the query that is being executed, and explicitly assigning weights to specific sub queries. You can provide a numeric weight to most query element, usually as one of the last arguments. See for instance [https://docs.marklogic.com/cts:word-query](https://docs.marklogic.com/cts%3aword-query). You can use this with search:search, and REST api search as well when using a structuredQuery.

The third is very flexible as well, and requires less knowledge about the actual query you are firing. It allows you to boost specific results at run-time. For instance boost more recent results, or boost results containing a particular term. Wrap you 'matching' query inside a `boost-query`, and provide separate queries that will cause boosting. See also [https://docs.marklogic.com/cts:boost-query](https://docs.marklogic.com/cts%3aboost-query).

The search dev guide mentioned by Mike also contains lots of good examples, including one for recent docs: https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/search-dev/relevance#id_99540. You can use these queries directly, or in a boost-query as the 'boosting' part, depending whether you want the boost to limit the search results as well or not..

HTH!